# Date subraction not working with date range function

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying subtract two datetimes when there valid there is valid value for  T1,T2 obtain the difference. The difference is caluclated by considering only weekdays between the dates not considering saturday and sunday.

Code works for only some rows. How can this be fixed.

```
       T1                       T2                  Diff
0   2017-12-04 05:48:15     2018-01-05 12:15:22     NaN
1   2017-07-10 08:23:11     2018-01-05 15:28:22     NaN
2   2017-09-11 05:10:37     2018-01-29 15:02:07     NaN
3   2017-12-21 04:51:12     2018-01-29 16:06:43     NaN
4   2017-10-13 10:11:00     2018-02-22 16:19:04     NaN
5   2017-09-28 21:44:31     2018-01-29 12:42:02     NaN
6   2018-01-23 20:00:58     2018-01-29 14:40:33     NaN
7   2017-11-28 15:39:38     2018-01-31 11:57:04     NaN
8   2017-12-21 12:44:00     2018-01-31 13:12:37     30.0
9   2017-11-09 05:52:29     2018-01-22 11:42:01     53.0
10  2018-02-12 04:21:08      NaT                    NaN

df[['T1','T2','diff']].dtypes
T1      datetime64[ns]
T2      datetime64[ns]
diff           float64


df['T1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T1'])
df['T2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t2'])

    def fun(row):
        if row.isnull().any():
            return np.nan
        ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(row["T1"],row["T2"]), columns=["date"])
        ts["dow"] = ts["date"].dt.weekday
        return (ts["dow"]<5).sum()

    df["diff"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: What happens when it doesn't work? Error message or incorrect data? Can you give us some output?

Comment: @RightmireM,  I have pasted the output ( its called diff ) on the question . It not giving correct values for all rows. i.e even if there is valid values it returns NULL. I want  return NULL values when there is NULL value in either of the input dates( T1,T2)

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. If you can provide raw data in comma separated format, then probably `NaN` issue can be resolved.

Comment: Well, an interesting bump. I recreated your code, and inserted a `print("ts=", ts)` right below the `ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(row["T1"],row["T2"]), columns=["date"])` and ... it never hit that row. For me, the `if row.isnull().any():` is always returning `np.nan`- If you try this, what do you see?

Comment: For me, if condition is `False` for my sample data. If you can give your sample data in comma separated format, then I can check on that.

Comment: @RightmireM, I still getting the same issue . I guess it beacuse some format issue. I am sharing sample data in a csv [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5lnr2jj81mextv/test.csv?dl=0). Could have a look

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to check for a null value in the row, use a try/except to capture the error when it does the calculation with a null value.

This worked for me in, I think, the manner you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("/home/rightmire/Downloads/test.csv", sep=",")
# df = df[["m1","m2"]]
print(df)
# print(df[['m1','m2']].dtypes)

df['m1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m1'])
df['m2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['m2'])

print(df[['m1','m2']].dtypes)

#for index, row in df.iterrows():
def fun(row):
    try:
        ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(row["m1"],row["m2"]), columns=["date"])
        # print(ts)
        ts["dow"] = ts["date"].dt.weekday
        result = (ts["dow"]<5).sum()
        # print("Result = ", result)
        return result

    except Exception as e:
        # print("ERROR:{}".format(str(e))) 
        result = np.nan
        # print("Result = ", result)
        return result

df["diff"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
print(df["diff"])
```

**OUTPUT OF INTEREST:**

```
dtype: object
0     275.0
1     147.0
2      58.0
3      28.0
4      95.0
5      87.0
6       4.0
7      46.0
8      30.0
9      96.0
10      NaN
11     27.0
12    170.0
13    158.0
14     79.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am still getting same output as the mentioned earlier.

Comment: I guess it due format issue. I am sharing the sample file of same. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5lnr2jj81mextv/test.csv?dl=0)

Comment: I added some checking code to the script. Try running that. I'm specifically curious if the input data is actually ending up as DateTime. Any time you end up with a `NaN` as a result, you should also be throwing and catching an error. I added code to printout that error. I'm curious what that error is. Just to confirm, you did remove the `if row.isna().any():` check, right?

Comment: Yes, I removed that used code. Could try the same the sample data I shared and see if you still get same result

Comment: I've modified my answer's code. It works with the downloaded CSV. The issue may simply have been that I didn't include all the calculations in the `try:` portion, since thats the only thing significantly changed. Please try this code and see if ti works for you :)